# How is it possible to read data for topic analysis as one document per line?

Tags: r, quanteda

I try to run an lda topic modeling

Here the example of quanteda site:

```
require(quanteda)
require(quanteda.corpora)
require(lubridate)
require(topicmodels)
corp_news <- download('data_corpus_guardian')
corp_news_subset <- corpus_subset(corp_news, 'date' >= 2016)
ndoc(corp_news_subset)
dfmat_news <- dfm(corp_news, remove_punct = TRUE, remove = stopwords('en')) %>% 
    dfm_remove(c('*-time', '*-timeUpdated', 'GMT', 'BST')) %>% 
    dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 0.95, termfreq_type = "quantile", 
             max_docfreq = 0.1, docfreq_type = "prop")
```

My data have this format:

```
dtext = data.frame(text = c("This dataset contains movie reviews along with their associated binary sentiment polarity labels. It is intended to serve as a benchmark for sentiment classification. This document outlines how the dataset was gathered, and how to use the files provided.", "The core dataset contains 50,000 reviews split evenly into 25k train and 25k test sets. The overall distribution of labels is balanced (25k pos and 25k neg). We also include an additional 50,000 unlabeled documents for unsupervised learning.", "There are two top-level directories [train/, test/] corresponding to the training and test sets. Each contains [pos/, neg/] directories for the reviews with binary labels positive and negative. Within these directories, reviews are stored in text files named following the convention [[id]_[rating].txt] where [id] is a unique id and [rating] is the star rating for that review on a 1-10 scale. For example, the file [test/pos/200_8.txt] is the text for a positive-labeled test set example with unique id 200 and star rating 8/10 from IMDb. The [train/unsup/] directory has 0 for all ratings because the ratings are omitted for this portion of the dataset."),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If I try to convert them into a corpus all data are made as one document. However every row is one document for me.

How should I modigy the corpus in order to read as one document per line in lda?

Comment: If I use `corpus(dtext)` I get a corpus consisting of 3 documents and 0 docvars.

Comment: The object `dtext` contains of 3 documents and no other variables. What do you expect to happen? There are no lines in the texts in `dtext`.

Comment: It's unclear why the Guardian corpus code is included. It's also unclear what "one document per line" means. Please clarify what the starting point is and what your desired end result is, with a clear example.